# django on_delete when adding post author

Tags: python, django, model

for the on_delete I am seeing this error:
`File "/home/kensei/Documents/school/bubbles/models.py", line 11, in bubbles user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,) TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete`

for this file in my app

```
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.
class bubbles(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,)
    
    content     = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.content)
```

even with several alterations attempting to add on_delete

Answer (score 0):

Change your following line:
`user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,)`
for
`user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

or see more options for the delete options on the [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Comment: yeah attemped that and it gave me ``` File "/home/kensei/Documents/school/bubbles/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class bubbles(models.Model):
  File "/home/kensei/Documents/school/bubbles/models.py", line 6, in bubbles
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, content  = models.CharField(max_length=200))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
``` so off to the docs again it is

Comment: Have you tried to `makemigrations` and `migrate` after making the change ?